# Replace native PHP functions to make it unicode compliant

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

Currently a (PHP5.4) web application I manage does not support unicode characters, so I want to convert it in order to support unicode (utf-8). Since future version (PHP6) may offer native unicode support I would like to keep the original native functions (e.g. trim(), strtoupper() etc) intact. Basically I want to override existing built in functions to do that.

The solution so far I came up with was to create one big include file to each page with the relevant functions and use namespaces, so for example:

```
    namespace my_ns;
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

    function strtoupper()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func_array('mb_strtoupper', $args );   
    }
```

However, in order for this to work i would have to add the namespace to each file, since namespaces are apparently bound to a single php-file.

My question is: is this the best way to go forward or are there better methods? Is there a way to 'autoload' namespaces automatically?

Help appreciated

**update:**

I found changing mbstring.func_overload in the php.ini file can override the existing functions, so that answers my question I guess.

Comment: It's pretty pointless to want to be forward-compatible with Unicode handling in PHP 6, because nobody has any clue what that will look like, when it will come out or how compatibility is going to be handled. Most likely you'll have to rewrite your app one way or another anyway.